# Using reactive extensions to handle key presses from a barcode reader

Tags: c#, winforms, system.reactive

I have my barcode reader programmed to add a prefix and suffix of "," and otherwise to work just like a keyboard. I have a Windows Form that will be open when barcodes are scanned.

Rather than writing a bunch of KeyDown code, Reactive Extensions seems perfect for this kind of work.  What I'd like to do:

- When a comma is pressed, start holding on to key presses (don't let them be handled by any control on the screen)
- Collect all keys until another comma is pressed or 250ms have gone by.
- If no comma is pressed within 250ms, hand the key presses back to whatever control is active.
- If comma is pressed, do processing on the string value scanned in from the barcode.

How can I use System.Reactive to hold key presses when matching a prefix and suffix for a barcode scanner, process if suffix is matched, but handle key presses normally when the suffix isn't matched within a time limit?

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone will come along and probably give a more elegant answer than this. But I found this one challenging.

First things first, this example does not show how to do it for keys on forms. There is sufficient additional complexity there that it bears trying yourself first, or asking another question. It would require a full application to answer all aspects of your question here. Suffice to say that:

1. You can turn KeyEventArgs into an observable that could be used in this framework
2. You can decide to suppress `KeyEventArgs` that make it into the barcode stream with [SuppressKeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.suppresskeypress.aspx)
3. You can decide to not suppress any `KeyEventArgs` in the non-barcode stream

The solution as it stands involves defining a function that takes an `IObservable<char>` and turns it into a `GroupedObservable` that marks (with a `bool`) whether the underlying char was inside a 'barcode' stream (true) or not (false):

```
public IObservable<IGroupedObservable<bool, IObservable<char>>> GroupBySurroundingChars(IObservable<char> source, char ends, TimeSpan within)
{
    var result = 
        source.Buffer(() => 
            source.Select(c => {
                if (c == ends) return source.Where(x => x == ends).Amb(Observable.Timer(within).Select(_ => default(char)));
                else           return Observable.Return(default(char));
            }).Concat())
            .GroupBy(buffer => buffer.Count > 2 && buffer[0] == ends && buffer.Last() == ends, buffer => buffer.ToObservable());                        

    return result;
}
```

What this function is doing is:

1. Starting a buffer with every character
2. If that character wasn't a comma, return the buffer immediately
3. If that character was a comma, hold the buffer open until another comma is found or 250ms have passed
4. Check if the buffer contains commas at either end (mark as a barcode) or not (mark as no barcode)

And then a full usage example:

```
var keys1 = "xxx,1234567,xxx,1,xxx".ToCharArray().ToObservable(Scheduler.ThreadPool).Do(_ => Thread.Sleep(100)).Publish().RefCount();
var keys2 = "xxx,1234567,xxx,1,xxx".ToCharArray().ToObservable(Scheduler.ThreadPool).Do(_ => Thread.Sleep(10)).Publish().RefCount();

var result = GroupBySurroundingChars(keys1, ',', TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));

var barcodes = result.Where(x => x.Key);
var others = result.Where(x => !x.Key);

barcodes.Subscribe(groups => groups.Subscribe(x => x.ToList().Dump()));
```

If you use `keys1`, the key presses are too slow to find the first barcode, but it finds the second. If you use `keys2`, the key presses are fast enough to find both barcodes.

In either case, the `others` stream contains all keys that were not eventually marked as containing barcodes. The `barcodes` stream can be taken as a character by character stream, or converted into a `List` with each set of barcodes as I did above.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take this apart piece by piece.

First you need the key presses as an Observable:

```
        var keys =
        Observable.FromEventPattern<KeyEventHandler, KeyEventArgs>(
                a => this.KeyDown += a,
                a => this.KeyDown -= a
            ).Select(ea => ea.EventArgs)
            .Publish();

        var unsubscription = keys.Connect();
```

You have a condition to delineate buffering, based on receiving a keypress:

```
        Func<KeyEventArgs, bool> isDelimiter =
            k => k.KeyCode == Keys.Oemcomma;
```

Now we can get notified whenever the buffer condition is met from `keys.Where(isDelimiter)`

We need to close the buffer when a delimiter is encountered OR some time has passed till no input was given:

```
Observable.Amb(keys.Where(isDelimiter), keys.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000))
```

Throwing these together, we have can create windows of characters which occur during these conditions:

```
        var windows = 
            keys.Window(keys.Where(isDelimiter),
                        first => Observable.Amb(
                                    keys.Where(isDelimiter), 
                                    keys.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000)
                                )
                                .Where(_ => isDelimiter(first))));
```

Now all you need to do is simply keep buffering till the window closes, and try and block the rest of the controls from receiving the keys while it is buffering:

```
        windows
            .SelectMany(window => window
                                        .Do(ka => ka.SuppressKeyPress = true)
                                        .Buffer(() => Observable.Never<KeyEventArgs>())
                                        )
            .Subscribe(buf => Trace.WriteLine(new string(buf.Select(ka => (char)ka.KeyValue).ToArray())));
```

`SelectMany` gets you the final stream of buffered keypresses, in which you can finally put in program logic. Here, I've simply printed the list to Trace as a string.

Comment: He wants to release keys to the program if the window doesn't close worth another comma but rather expires. Keeping that option around is the toughest part ...

Comment: @yamen This is too idealistic. I guess he'd have to check if the buffer ended with a trailing comma, and send the keys back to his application.

Comment: Just seems like the hardest part of the solution, so shouldn't be ignored. If I was him, I'd be inclined to use something far less common than a comma...

Comment: @yamen And possibly a sequence that doesn't both start and end in a comma. Maybe it's an app where all manner of punctuation is frowned upon. :P

Comment: @yamen If he wanted to 'release' the keys, he could use Win API to send the keys back to the form, but couldn't he just supply the buffer to the model which actually handles the key-press?

Comment: The comma isn't really my choice. It's part of the barcode driver.